# Testing hash contents using RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, expectations

I have a test like so:

```
it "should not indicate backwards jumps if the checker position is not a king" do
    board = Board.new
    game_board = board.create_test_board
    board.add_checker(game_board, :red, 3, 3)
    x_coord = 3
    y_coord = 3
    jump_locations = {}
    jump_locations["upper_left"]  = true 
    jump_locations["upper_right"] = false 
    jump_locations["lower_left"]  = false
    jump_locations["lower_right"] = true
    adjusted_jump_locations = @bs.adjust_jump_locations_if_not_king(game_board, x_coord, y_coord, jump_locations)
    adjusted_jump_locations["upper_left"].should == true 
    adjusted_jump_locations["upper_right"].should == false 
    adjusted_jump_locations["lower_left"].should == false
    adjusted_jump_locations["lower_right"].should == false
  end
```

which, I know, is verbose. Is there a more concise way to state my expectations? I've looked at the docs but I can't see where to compress my expectations. Thanks.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It works for hashes too:

```
expect(jump_locations).to include(
  "upper_left"  => true,
  "upper_right" => false,
  "lower_left"  => false,
  "lower_right" => true
)
```

Source:
[`include` matcher @ relishapp.com](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher)

Comment: Thanks, David. BTW Huge fan. Really enjoyed the RSpec book.

Comment: I wish there was a corresponding method like match_array

Comment: Ditto on the Fanage David!  Your "The Rspec Book" is well-thumbed!

Answer (score 38):

Just wanna add to @David's answer. You could nest and use matchers in your `include` hash. For example:

```rb
# Pass
expect({
  "num" => 5, 
  "a" => { 
    "b" => [3, 4, 5] 
  }
}).to include({
  "num" => a_value_between(3, 10), 
  "a" => {
    "b" => be_an(Array)
  }
})
```

A caveat: a nested `include` hash must test all keys or the test will fail, e.g.:

```rb
# Fail
expect({
  "a" => { 
    "b" => 1,
    "c" => 2
  }
}).to include({
  "a" => {
    "b" => 1
  }
})
```

Comment: You can solve your caveat by using nested includes:

```expect({
  "a" => { 
    "b" => 1,
    "c" => 2
  }
}).to include({
  "a" => include({
    "b" => 1
  })
})```

Comment: most matchers have both "verb" and longer "noun" aliases, the latter might read better when nesting: `expect({ "a" => { "b" => 1, "c" => 2 } }).to include({ "a" => a_hash_including({ "b" => 1 }) })`.  http://timjwade.com/2016/08/01/testing-json-apis-with-rspec-composable-matchers.html is a good blog post on this.

Comment: @AngelCabo your comment should be the accepted answer. Helps in so many scenarios.

Answer (score 8):

Syntax has changed for RSpec 3, but include matcher is still the one:

```
expect(jump_locations).to include(
  "upper_left" => true,
  "upper_right" => false,
  "lower_left" => false,
  "lower_right" => true
)
```

See [built-in-matchers#include-matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-5/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher).

Answer (score 5):

Another easy way to test if the whole content is a Hash is to checkout if the content is the Hash Object itself:

```
it 'is to be a Hash Object' do
    workbook = {name: 'A', address: 'La'}
    expect(workbook.is_a?(Hash)).to be_truthy
end
```

---

For the question above we can check as follow:

```rb
expect(adjusted_jump_locations).to match(hash_including('upper_left' => true))
```

Comment: The question is about testing Hash contents, not whether response is a Hash

Comment: @ToTenMilan that is why i stress it There is "Another way..." it might/might not help. It depends.