# Ruby Hash check is subset?

Tags: ruby, hash, subset, contain

How can I tell if if a Ruby hash is a subset of (or includes) another hash?

For example:

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7}
hash.include_hash?({})            # true
hash.include_hash?({f: 6, c: 3})  # true
hash.include_hash?({f: 6, c: 1})  # false
```

Comment: Matt, you seem to have been bestowed with an [embarrassment of riches](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/an-embarrassment-of-riches).  (Link for those for whom English is a second language.)  Getting four out of four quality answers on SO is pretty rare.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since Ruby 2.3 you can also do the following to check if this is a subset

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7}
{} <= hash           # true
{f: 6, c: 3} <= hash # true
{f: 6, c: 1} <= hash # false
```

Comment: does this work with nested hashes? Otherwise it's definitely a concise answer.

Comment: @nus it does work with nested hashes. However, the nested hash must equal the other, so it can't be just a subset:
`{a: {x:1, y:2}} <= {a: {x:1, y:2}, b:3 } # true`
`{a: {x:1}}        <= {a: {x:1, y:2}, b:3 } # false`

Comment: Also works the other way around: `hash >= {f: 6, c: 3}`

Answer (score 16):

The solution that came into my mind use [`Hash#merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) method:

```
class Hash
  def include_hash?(hash)
    merge(hash) == self
  end
end

hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7}
hash.include_hash?({})
# => true
hash.include_hash?(f: 6, c:3)
# => true
hash.include_hash?(f: 6, c:1)
# => false
```

Comment: And for nested hash you can use `active support`'s [deep_merge](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge)

Comment: This is very elegant. I call mine `superset?` though, and I made `subset?` as well.

Comment: If you're looking to build assertions that test against nested hash values in RSpec, you can use Rspec's `includes` matcher. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29248139/590767. Using `include_hash?` in tests would only print out true or false and is less informative than the `includes` approach.

Answer (score 8):

Array difference seems easiest:

```
class Hash
  def include_hash?(h)
    (h.to_a - to_a).empty?
  end
end

h = {a: 1, b: 2}
h.include_hash?({b: 2}) #=> true
h.include_hash?({b: 3}) #=> false
```

Comment: I understand `(h.to_a - to_a)`.. But for better readbility `(h.to_a - self.to_a)`... IMO

Comment: @Arup, I respectfully disagree, though I know your view is shared by many others.  Imo, `self.to_a` suggests that `self` is needed here (as it would be if it were followed by an accessor or `class`).  I think it is always best to avoid using `self` when it is not required.  If a reader is confused by `to_a` without `self`, they will quickly figure it out, and learn something in the bargain.

Answer (score 7):

You could convert the hashes to [sets](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) and than perform the check using the methods `subset?` and `superset?` (or their respective aliases `<=` and `>=`):

```
require 'set'

hash.to_set.superset?({}.to_set)
# => true

hash.to_set >= {a: 1}.to_set
# => true

{a: 2}.to_set <= hash.to_set 
# => false
```

**Update**: a benchmark of the proposed solutions:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'set'

hash = ('aa'..'zz').zip('aa'..'zz').to_h
# {"aa"=>"aa", "ab"=>"ab", ...
find = ('aa'..'zz').zip('aa'..'zz').select { |k, _| k[0] == k[1] }.to_h 
# {"aa"=>"aa", "bb"=>"bb", ...

compare(
  toro2k:        -> { hash.to_set >= find.to_set },
  MarekLipka:    -> { hash.merge(find) == hash },
  CarySwoveland: -> { (find.to_a - hash.to_a).empty? },
  ArupRakshit:   -> { arr = hash.to_a; find.all? { |pair| arr.include?(pair) } }
)
```

Result:

```
Running each test 2 times. Test will take about 1 second.
MarekLipka is faster than toro2k by 3x ± 0.1
toro2k is faster than CarySwoveland by 39.99999999999999% ± 10.0%
CarySwoveland is faster than ArupRakshit by 1.9x ± 0.1
```

Comment: Thanks! Based on `Set#superset?`, I should call the method `Hash#superset?` instead of `Hash#include_hash?`.

Comment: Probably `superset?` would be a better name, however I think it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Wow I'd just like to say thanks for introducing me to the [fruity gem](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity)!  That's awesome.

Comment: Good solutions, toro, and thanks for the fruity benchmarks. (I'd never heard of fruity, and hadn't noticed the require until I read @Nick's comment).

Answer (score 6):

You can do :

```
def include_hash?(hash,subset_hash)
   arr = hash.to_a
   subset_hash.all? { |pair| arr.include?(pair) }
end
```

Comment: Can anyone check if `subset_hash.all? { |pair| arr.include?(pair) }` is also working or not... I am away from computer, so couldn't test the same..

Comment: I checked with some test cases, and it appears to work correctly.

Comment: It reads very well--easy to quickly understand what you are doing.